# How to set NonNull to node and edges in connection class?

Tags: graphene-python, graphene-sqlalchemy

I'd like to add NonNull to node and edges in connection.

```
class TestSchema(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)
    id = graphene.ID(required=True)
```

when I looked at document explorer in Graphql playground,

in TestSchemaConnection

```
edges: [TestSchemaEdge]!
```

and in TestSchemaEdge

```
node: TestSchema
```

But I want "!" inside brackets not to be nullable like below.

```
edges: [TestSchemaEdge!]! 

node: TestSchema!
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible, as of: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/968

Seems like it is addressed as an issue, but not worked on.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).